# Confused about why a path $ \gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth if $\gamma'(t) \neq 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In Edwards Advanced Calculus Ch 5 Section 1, a $ \mathcal{C}^1$ (continuous and differentiable) path $ \gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be *smooth* if $ \gamma'(t) \neq \textbf{0}$ for all $ t \in [a,b]$.

I don't see why this implies the path is smooth. Is there an intuitive or visual explanation?

Also, say $ \gamma(t) = (t^3, t^3)$. According to the definition given, because $ \gamma'(0) = (0,0)$, this is not a smooth path. I don't see why it isn't smooth, because the path is just a straight line in $ \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Note that $\gamma$ must be not only continuous, but also differentiable

Comment: You're right, I'll add that detail

Comment: The key is to see that the restriction $\gamma' \neq 0$ *prevents* the kinks that are visibly "non-smooth".  For example, I think you'd agree that $\gamma(t) = (t^3,t^2)$ is not *smooth*.

Answer (score 2):

The key to intuition here is to see that the restriction $\gamma' \neq 0$ *prevents* the kinks that are visibly "non-smooth".  For example, I think you'd agree that $\gamma(t) = (t^3,t^2)$ is not *smooth*, by any definition.

Note also that this terminology describes particular choices of parameterization rather than the curve itself (i.e. the image of the parameterization in $\Bbb R^n$).  For example, with $\gamma(t) = (t^3,t^3)$, we might say that *the image of $\gamma$ is a smooth curve* even though $\gamma$ is not itself a smooth parameterization.  We know that this image, a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, is "smooth" (i.e. a smooth $1$-manifold) because it has the smooth parametrization $\gamma(t) = (t,t)$, even if it has some non-smooth parameterizations as well.

Comment: Just to visualize this better: say $\gamma'(t)$ at some point is very close to the zero vector, but not exactly 0. Would that give us something close to a kink? 
And if for some $t$ $\gamma'(t)$ is zero in all components except one, would that give us something close to a kink?

Comment: Also, this was a textbook definition, so the "if" should actually mean "iff". But then $\gamma(t) = (t^3, t^2+1)$ would be smooth because nowhere does $\gamma'(t) = 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are: $(t^3,t^2+c)'=(t^3,t^2)'$...

Comment: Yes, you are: $(t^3,t^2+c)'=(t^3,t^2)'$...